# Join rows from two different queries

Tags: sql, join, rows

I have a table `sales_table` with a id,date and sales fields.

> no          date          sales
>   ----------------------------------------------------
>   1          1-Jan          10,000
>   2          3-Jan          12,500
>   3          4-Jan          8,000
>   4          5-Jan          12,000
>   5          8-Jan          10,000
>   "          "          "
>  "          "          "
>  "          "          "
>  "          "          "
>  "          "          "
>  "          "          "
>  "          "          "
>  "          "          "
>  "          "          "
>  100          13-Mar          4000

the date  is unique but not always in series. the no is unique and in series with a incremented no of each higher date.

I am looking to get the difference between the sales of the current and previous date. something like

> no              
>   date              
>   sales              
>   diff              
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1              
>   1-Jan              
>   10,000              
>   0              
>   2              
>   3-Jan              
>   12,500              
>   2500              
>   3              
>   4-Jan              
>   8,000              
>   -4500              
>   4              
>   5-Jan              
>   12,000              
>   4000              
>   5              
>   8-Jan              
>   10,000              
>   -2000

I am using a sql query-

```
select t1.no,t1.date,t1.sales (t1.sales-2.sales) as diff 
from sales_table as t1,sales_table as t2 
where(t1.no=t2.no+1) order by t1.date
```

This works fine except i get records starting from no 2.

so i have written another another sql query -

```
select no,date,sales,sales-sales as diff 
from sales_table 
where(no=1)
```

which outputs as-
    1, 1-Jan,10000,0.

How can i join rows from both these queries?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different options depending on your database.  One option is to modify your existing query to use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
select t1.no,t1.date,t1.sales,(t1.sales-coalesce(t2.sales,t1.sales)) as diff 
from sales_table as t1
    left join sales_table as t2 on t1.no=t2.no+1
order by t1.date
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96be8/1)